# How to resolve "org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document root element "property", must match DOCTYPE root "jasperReport"." error?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am getting error while developing Pdf in Java

Error is:

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document root element "property", must match DOCTYPE root "jasperReport".

How to fix it?

Comment: I don't know what the question is

Answer (score 0):

The error says your jasper design doesn't have the expected structure (the root element should be jasperReport, not property)
. Make sure your .jrxml file is correct or use [iReport](http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport)